# Accidentally wiped laptop

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, laptop, acer, usb-installation

I tried many times to install Ubuntu from a bootable USB, but I would go through the entire installation process, just to get to the end restart the laptop, unplug the bootable USB and then it doesn't boot into Ubuntu.

Then I had an idea. I thought if I bought an adaptor for SATA to USB I could disassemble the laptop and install Ubuntu directly onto its internal HDD, so I formatted the HDD and using Rufus I picked the hardrive and put the ISO on the disk.

Now whenever I turn on my laptop the fan revs up really really loudly. After waiting 5 minutes, still a black screen.

Then even when I put my windows 10 CD disk into the laptop that doesn't do anything either.

*How should I proceed*

Comment: Disconnecting a drive, removes UEFI entries. You should be able to just add one back for Windows. But Acer requires you to enable "trust" from within UEFI for ubuntu/grub .efi boot files. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot  & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not an Ubuntu question any more, but more of a [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com) question (One of our sister sites in the Stack Exchange Network).

Unfortunately for you the answer is:

- contact your manufacturer and ask them for a Restore CD as most modern machines have their BIOS on the HDD nowadays. (aka "[UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78582/what-is-uefi-and-secure-boot-how-do-they-affect-ubuntu)").
- If that doesn't work, return the laptop for professional repair...

### Sorry! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯